# What is 'Refresh Rate' in the context of machine learning algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I've recently been using an AI/ML platform called Monument(Monument.Ai) to project time series. The platform contains various ML algos and parameters within the algo to tune the projections. When using algos such as Light GBM and LSTM, there is a parameter called 'Refresh Rate.' Refresh rate is a parameter that takes in an integer. In the platform, it describes refresh rate as

> How frequently windows are constructed. Every window is used to validate this number of data points

where windows in this context are 'sub windows' within the main training period. My question is what is the underlying use of refresh rate and how does changing it from 1, 10, or 50 impact the projections?

Comment: You can also get help on the Monument subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/MonumentAI/

Answer (score 1):

*Monument* worker here. I think we should set up an Faq platform somewhere, as the questions could be confusing to others without context :-)

Back to your question, the `refresh rate` affects only the "validation" part for a time series analysis. It is interpreted as a frequency number, so 1 = high refresh rate and 50 = low refresh rate. A higher refresh rate gives you the better validation effectiveness, but is slower than a lower refresh rate; hence you usually choose a moderate one (10 is a good choice).

====== More technical explanations below. ======

On *Monument*, you choose an algorithm to make future "prediction" on your time series data, and look at the "validation" results to see how suitable the algorithm is to your problem. The prediction task is specified by two "window" parameters: `lookback` and `lookahead`. Selecting `lookback=10` and `lookahead=5` means you are trying to "predict 5 data points into the future by using the last 10 data points".

Validation needs to reflect the result from the exact same prediction task. Particularly, for **each** historical data point, you want to train a **new** model with 10 points in the past to predict 5 points ahead. This is when `refresh rate=1`, i.e., refresh for every data point. For each historical data point, you create a "sub-window" of length 15 (10+5). That is a lot of new models to train and could be very very slow.

If time and memory limit is not a concern then `refresh rate=1` is a good choice, but usually we want to be more efficient. Here we are exploiting a "local reusability" assumption, that is a model trained for a sub-window is useful for adjacent sub-windows. Then we can train model on one sub-window and use it on 10 historical points, that is, `refresh rate=10`. This way much less computation is required and validation is still accurate to a certain extent. Note you may not want to set `refresh rate=200`, because it is not very convincing that my model is still useful for data 200 points away. As you see there is a tradeoff between speed and accuracy.